# Osmdroid custom marker drawables can't draw text or shapes

Tags: android, drawing, osmdroid

I'm currently using the latest `osmdroid` library (3.0.10) to show my custom markers on a map with an `ItemizedOverlay`. I've extended the Drawable class to implement my own drawing. However my `drawables` are not drawn correctly. I draw a bitmap image, a circle and a text on top of each other. The bitmap is drawn, but the circle and the text is not visible. When I use the same drawable in an `imageview`, everything is OK.

Here is the code of my drawable's onDraw method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(getBounds().left, getBounds().top);
    //this draws fine
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,mWidth,mWidth), mPaint);
    //this is not
    canvas.drawCircle(mHeight/2, mHeight/2, mHeight/2, mPaint);
    //neither
    canvas.drawText("X", mHeight/2, mHeight/2, mPaint2);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

I've tried drawing the circle and the text on a bitmap, and drawing that on the provided canvas. It's working but that kills the whole point.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of going trough the osmdroid sources, i managed to resolve my problems, but haven't found why are they there in the first place. Osmdroid uses an ISafeCanvas interface (and SafeTranslatedCanvas implementation) to wrap a canvas to deal with some high zoom level translate glitches. While I haven't found any straightforward errors in the code, I bypassed the mechanics when drawing my overlays by overriding the ItemizedOverlay's draw method and making my own ISafeCanvas implementation, which only returns the encapsulated canvas in it's getSafeCanvas method, and now everything looks fine.

```
@Override
protected void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow) {
    drawSafe(new MyCanvas(canvas),mv,shadow);
}
```

This is far from a best solution, the SafeCanvas is there for a reason, so I suggest a thorough testing  if using this method.

Note: I used only Android 4.1.1, and don't know if this issue is present on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Issue 427](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=427). Essentially you want to use:

```
canvas.getUnsafeCanvas(new UnsafeCanvasHandler() {
                             // Draw circle and text here
                             // (but not drawBitmap)
            });
```

Keep an eye on the ticket for a more permanent solution.